# The як частка чогось

Tags: переклад, from-english

Історик Ярослав Грицак

> Україна звучить в двох англійських варіантах. Вона звучить як the
>   Ukraine і звучить як просто Ukraine. ... ,бо the означає частка чогось.

Я безуспішно вивчав англійську мову, ще за часів, коли the взагалі ніяк не перекладали українською мовою. Сьогодні вже в уроках з англійської можна побачити, що the перекладають як цей, ця, ці. І використання the стало зрозуміліше.

Коли історик каже про використання артикля у значенні, про яке ніде раніше не зустрічав, то це стає цікаво. Може я не ті книжки якісь читаю про англійську мову ...

Можливо хтось знає де знайти пояснення про значення the як "частка чогось" або ширше пояснення the, щоб зрозуміти як перекласти подібний випадок українською або використовувати в англійській?

Або можливо вкажете мені на це правило [звідси](https://grammarway.com/ua/article) чи з іншого джерела і я спробую його зрозуміти.

Comment: Це запитання має політично-важливу тематику, але воно не відповідає топіку про українську мову. Іншими словами, абстрактний «знавець української мови» з усіма своїми знаннями не може відповісти, чому англомовні пишуть чи не пишуть *„the“*.

Comment: @bytebuster Ви можете довести своє твердження щодо того, хто може відповісти на запитання, а хто ні? Куди тоді писати подібне запитання?

Comment: @bytebuster Чому ви мене обізвали відчайдушним? Поясніть, будь ласка.

Comment: Перепрошую, якщо вам здалося це особистим, зовсім не це мається на увазі. Це наслідок старих дискусій на іншу тему (напіввідповідей у коментарях), де аргументом захисників неякісних дописів є сентенція на кшталт «якщо ви видаляєте поганий допис, то куди ж подітися відчайдушному автору запитання зі своїм запитанням?» Ну, і відповідно, літературний прийом — [тут](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/222/8) використовується термін *„the hapless questioner“*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Досить розлого на це відповіли [тут](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/24661/49889). Я перекладу вам ту відповідь і постараюся також зрозуміти, чи це якось впливає на український переклад.

#### Далі переклад:

Називання країн — це радше питання політики й усталеного вжитку, а не ґраматики. Наприклад, більше не прийнято говорити *the Ukraine*, адже уряд цієї країни виступає проти цього, а деяких людей це навіть може [ображати](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/country-names-and-the-the-ukraine-or-ukraine).

---

В принципі, кожна країна може оголосити, як її треба коротко та офіційно називати анґлійською, хоч це й не завжди впливає на загальний вжиток. Так, використання *Holland* на позначення *the Netherlands* продовжувалося аж до другої половини 20 століття, а *Burma* досі лишається *Burma*, мабуть, для того, щоби подратувати ґенералів, які наполягають на назві *Myanmar*.

Означений артикль "the" використовується тоді, коли:

1. назва країни містить власну назву, яка зазвичай вказує на вид держави; так: *Russia*, але *the Russian Federation*; *Britain* але *the UK* та *the United Kingdom*; *the UAE* та *the United Arab Emirates*. Офіційна назва країни дуже часто містить артикль: *China*, але *the People's Republic of China* (або *the Republic of China*); *Jordan*, але *the Hashemite Kingdom of Jordan*; *Gabon*, але *the Gabonese Republic*.

   Але є й винятки. Пишемо *Vatican City*, а не *the Vatican City* — хоч його також називають *the Holy See* (Священне Море).
2. назва стосується ґеоґрафічного чи культурного регіону, ґрупи островів та подібного: *The Bahamas*, *The Gambia*, *the Comoros*, *the Netherlands* тощо. З того, що мені відомо, Ґамбія й Багами — це єдині країни, що віддають перевагу використанню артикля "the" з великою першою літерою. (Серед міст можна назвати The Hague і The Bronx, і [ще кілька](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28177).)

Окремо треба розглянути випадок, коли *the* видаляється з назв багатьох країн; означений артикль може значити, що країну сприймають за реґіон в межах чогось більшого, а в цьому часто вбачають [колоніальні нотки](http://www.bbc.com/news/magazine-18233844). Отже, те, що кілька десятиліть тому називали *the Lebanon* [гора], *the Argentine* [ріка], *the Ukraine* [=окраїна], and *the Sudan* [пустеля], сьогодні вже називають *Lebanon*, *Argentina*, *Ukraine* і *Sudan*.

Коли назву запозичують з іншої мови, то артикль мові-ориґіналі іґнорують. Тому *El Salvador*, а не *the Salvador*, а також піднаціональні утворення на кшталт *Le Havre* або *Los Angeles*.

#### Тепер до української мови:

Україна в українській мові станом на сьогодні завжди пишеться як Україна. Незалежно від того, чи є в англійській мові означений артикль, чи його немає, перекладатися назва нашої країни буде як "Україна".

Найближчий відповідник до такого розрізнення, як в англійській, це прийменники "на" і "в", які стоять перед "Україні". Якщо йдеться про переклад історичного джерела, можливо, є сенс задуматись, чи не перекласти, наприклад, вислів "in the Ukraine" як "на Україні", щоби показати, що автор не сприймав Україну як окрему державу (якою ми не встигли дуже довго побути за останні століття), а сприймав її як реґіон.

Також цікавий такий факт: якщо сьогодні в Україні вже прийнято писати "в" перед назвою країни, то ще не так давно дуже поважні мовознавці та письменники могли написати "на". У [корпусі](http://www.parasolcorpus.org/bonito/run.cgi/view?q=aword%2C%5Blc%3D%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%20%7C%20lemma_lc%3D%22%D0%BD%D0%B0%22%5D%5Blc%3D%22%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%22%20%7C%20lemma_lc%3D%22%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96%22%5D;fromp=2;corpname=grac7&attrs=word&ctxattrs=word&structs=g&refs=%3Ddoc.author%2C%3Ddoc.translator%2C%3Ddoc.title%2C%3Ddoc.date&pagesize=100&icon_copy=1&iquery=%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%96;navpos=next2), наприклад, можна знайти декілька текстів, де Іван Багряний, Тодось Осьмачка, Максим Рильський і Юрій Шевельов у 1944 році вживають саме цей прийменник.

#### Висновки:

Як на мене, перекладати майже у всіх випадках треба просто як "Україна", незалежно від того, чи в анґлійській стоїть означений артикль перед назвою країни, чи не стоїть (перекладена відповідь доводить, що означений артикль потроху зникатиме перед назвою нашої країни в анґлійській мові). Єдина ситуація (яку я можу уявити), де є сенс ненадовго задуматись, чи змінюється сенс від того, чи стоїть там означений артикль — при виборі прийменника "на" чи "в", коли йдеться про обставину місця в історичних творах.

Comment: Я зрозумів це так, що все ж можна перекласти the Ukraine, як ця Україна, або  the Somecountry як ця Деякакраїна. Просто потрібно щоразу розуміти про що кажуть, коли використовують значення ця. Тобто визначеність визначена лише тоді, коли розумієш зміст. Якщо не розумієш зміст, то the всеодно не визначене. Типу коли в нас кажуть: "ну цей, як його", то чітко вказують на невизначену визначеність. Цей у нашому випадку означає усю суть використання артиклю в англійській мові. Дякую.

Comment: Хмм, то слово "це" можна віднести до артиклю? ... просто ми його використовуємо трохи по іншому.

Comment: Перепрошую, але -1, тому що модератори повинні знати межі топіку сайту і скеровувати offtopic-запитання або на правильний сайт, або на закриття. І — ні, *helping a desperate asker* не виглядає слушним виправданням.

Comment: @ bytebuster Чому не по темі?

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko, не по темі, тому що запитання не про українську мову. Воно про англійську мову, воно про [політику](https://politics.stackexchange.com/a/10705/2984) і навіть, можливо, про [подорожі](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4702/26641). Але не про українську мову. І, як бачите за посиланнями, там, де таким запитанням — місце, навіть я долучався до них. :)

Comment: @bytebuster Зрозумів. Бувайте.

Comment: @AndriyIvanchenko дивіться, ви накладаєте використання означенного артикля в межах загального вжитку на використання з країнами, коли різниця в цих використаннях дуже велика. Я чітко переклав, як це працює з країнами. Немає сенсу додавати "ця" до "Україна", бо це в нашій мові не пояснить колоніального присмаку "the" доданого до "Ukraine".

Comment: @bytebuster людина питає, як відрізняється переклад "Ukraine" i "the Ukraine" з англійської. Я не розумію, відколи питання про переклад стали off-topic.